# Adding user to an Organization in Trello

Tags: trello, user-accounts

I just created an Organization, added a user who accepted the invitation, and created a board, with Organization visibility only.
When I, as an admin, create a new card and try to assign it to the other user (who *is* part of the organization), I don't see him in the members list and he doesn't show up in the Members list on the right panel of the Board. He is, however, listed in the members of the organization.
If I do log with his credentials, eventhough he is admin, I can't edit any card.

Did I missed something?

Comment: Okay.. seems I missed the 'invite to Board' thing.. user has been invited to the join the Organization, but needs ALSO to be invited to the specific board.. Thought being invited to an join an Organization would give full access to ALL boards of that Organization...

Answer (score 3):

We're trying to strike a balance between being easy to use for small organizations (where you expect all organization members to be on all boards) and large organizations (where that would be a lot of clutter). Here is our current plan: https://trello.com/card/board/make-it-easier-to-add-organization-members-to-a-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e863e8b7c30b184f69bf9a3

From that card:

**The way it works now**

You have to individually invite every org member to an org board, there is no indication that they are part of your org in the invite process, they have to go through another acceptance process.

**The way it will work**

Any member added to an org can add any other member of that org to an org board, without an invite process. They've already accepted your org invite, so you already trust them. They will get a notification that they've been added. The 'add members' pane will list all org members, making it easy to just click and add them. There will be an 'add all org members' button that... adds all org members.

**Things we're considering**

- Members of an organization can self-invite themselves to an organization board
- If an organization owner is added to a board, they become a board owner automatically